# New TX math font symbol: skew underbrace with package newtxmath

Tags: math-mode, packages, newtx

I found that the New TX math font `newtxmath` could not displace `underbrace`, see: latest Texlive 2012

[image]

The correct `underbrace` with default CM font:
[image]

---

It's weird that it works well when I test it with a simple `tex` file.

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{book}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}  % new TX times

  \begin{document}


  \begin{eqnarray}
  \frac{\sin^{2}\vartheta}{\Theta_{lm}(\vartheta)}\left(\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\vartheta^{2}}+\frac{\cos\vartheta}{\sin\vartheta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\vartheta}\right)\Theta_{lm}(\vartheta)+\sin^{2}(\vartheta)(l(l+1)) =\underbrace{-\frac{1}{\Phi_{m}(\varphi)}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\varphi^{2}}\Phi_{m}(\varphi)}_{blabla} \\
  P_l (x)\equiv\frac {1}{2^l}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor l/2\rfloor} (-1)^k \frac{(2l-2k)!}{k!(l-k)!(l-2k)!} x^{l-2k}\\
  \iint_\Omega \frac{x^2+1}{2y}dxdy = 0
  \end{eqnarray}

  \end{document}
```

But it won't work with these packages used for my report:

```
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{enumerate}     % numbered items
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{booktabs}    
 \usepackage{threeparttable}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}  % ngerman: "a "s "o "u
 \usepackage{subfigure}
 \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}  % ref
 \usepackage{natbib}                % bibtex
 \usepackage{cases}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{algpseudocode} 
 \usepackage{wallpaper}

 % | * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * |
 % |        fonts with math support          |
 % | * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * |

 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}  % new TX times

 \usepackage{esint}     % Alternate integrals signs
 \usepackage{ngerman}  % after package mathdesign !
```

The rest packages and setting are for page layout, margin, etc.

---

I am sure `newtxmath` conflicts with some certain packages, How to figure this out?

---

Partial solution: Putting `esint` before `newtxmath` will eliminate this issue, but it produces the unchanged `\iint` symbol:
[image]

Comment: Works for me. Which version of `newtx` do you use?

Comment: i'd start by getting a font chart of the "extension font" (the one comparable to `cmex`).  i would then unpack the `.tfm` file for that font with `tftopl`.  the documentation for that program (`texdoc tftopl`) is going to be useful.  what you want to look for is the "math extension scheme" which will have a recipe for starting, extension, middle, extension, ending pieces.  the character cell location in the font is wrong for the extension piece.  replace that location value by the correct one (it is probably the same as the one for `\overbrace`) and repackage with `pltotf`.

Comment: @barbara beeton, the method you provided seems very complicated!

Comment: yes, it is complicated, but it permits one to patch a `.tfm` file if it contains an error.  it's the "original" method, in use for 30+ years.  there may be other methods now to patch `.tfm` files, but this is the one i've used successfully in the past.  and it does seem that you found it was not a problem with the font itself, but with incompatibilities when using another package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Load the redefinition from package `esint` after `newtxmath` with another name for the Symbol font because both packages load it with the same name `largesymbolsA`:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{book}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{esint,newtxtext, newtxmath}  % new TX times
\makeatletter
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsB}{U}{esint}{m}{n}% esint uses largesymbolsA
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsB}{'001}
        \def\int{\intop\nolimits}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsB}{'003}
        \def\iint{\iintop\nolimits}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\iiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsB}{'005}
        \def\iiint{\iiintop\nolimits}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\iiiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsB}{'007}
        \def\iiiint{\iiiintop\nolimits}
\makeatother
 \begin{document}
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \int \iint \iiint 
  \frac{\sin^{2}\vartheta}{\Theta_{lm}(\vartheta)}\left(\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\vartheta^{2}}+\frac{\cos\vartheta}{\sin\vartheta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\vartheta}\right)\Theta_{lm}(\vartheta)+\sin^{2}(\vartheta)(l(l+1)) =\underbrace{-\frac{1}{\Phi_{m}(\varphi)}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\varphi^{2}}\Phi_{m}(\varphi)}_{blabla} \\
  P_l (x)\equiv\frac {1}{2^l}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor l/2\rfloor} (-1)^k \frac{(2l-2k)!}{k!(l-k)!(l-2k)!} x^{l-2k}
  \end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you put {esint} before `newtxmath`, the `\iint` symbol is the same as the one without {esint} package.

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: hmmm, it seems not working.

Comment: @KOF: see my complete example which works.

Comment: Great, it works perfectly now. Seems I need to learn some basic TEX commands to re-define the original packages.

Comment: @KOF: Both packages uses the same name `largesymbolsA` for the symbol font ...

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out this issue: `{newtxmath}` is not compatible with the package `{esint}`!

When using `{esint}` to display neat `\iint` integral symbol, it must be put after the package of `math font`, but in this case, it produced wrong `underbrace` symbol.