# Underbrace using STIX2 math font

Tags: fontspec, polyglossia, unicode-math, mathtools, stix

The problem speaks for itself, here is the sample:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%% Language of the document
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

%% Text font of the document
\setmainfont{STIX2Text-Regular.otf}[
    BoldFont       = STIX2Text-Bold.otf , 
    ItalicFont     = STIX2Text-Italic.otf, 
    BoldItalicFont = STIX2Text-BoldItalic.otf
]

%% Math font of the document
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}    
    \[
    \underbrace{\text{A long equation}}_{\text{This is a long equation}}
    \]  
\end{document}
```

and when compiled, the underbrace it's just not there. Of course I'm missing something in the configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `mathtools` package contains a fix to `\underbrace` and `\overbrace` as defined in the LaTeX kernel.

If we compare the two definitions

```latex
%%% LaTeX kernel
\DeclareRobustCommand\underbrace[1]{\mathop{\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
   $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr
   \noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
   \upbracefill\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}}}}\limits}

%%% mathtools.sty
\def\underbrace#1{\mathop{\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
   $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr
   \noalign{\kern.7\fontdimen5\textfont2\nointerlineskip}%
   \upbracefill\crcr\noalign{\kern.5\fontdimen5\textfont2}}}}\limits}
```

we see that they're almost identical, but `mathtools` improves the definition by not using a fixed length of 3pt and adjusting it with the current math font setup.

However, the definition of `\underbrace` in `unicode-math` is

```latex
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"023DF}{\underbrace}{\mathunder}{bottom curly bracket (mathematical use)}
```

that translates to more low level

```latex
\underbrace=\protected macro:
#1->\mathop {\Umathaccent bottom 7\symoperators "023DF\scan_stop: {{}#1}}\limits
```

What happens if you load `mathtools` *after* `unicode-math` is that the “Unicode” definition of `\underbrace` is overridden with the fix above done by `mathtools`.
Note that you get no error: indeed `\upbracefill` uses math characters that in `unicode-math` don't correspond to the pieces of brace as in legacy LaTeX math fonts.

In conclusion: `mathtools` makes a good fix for legacy math fonts, but it shouldn't do it when `unicode-math` is loaded. Until `mathtools` is updated, the solution is to load it *before* `unicode-math`.

Answer (score 10):

One should load the `mathtools` package *before* the `fontspec` and/or `unicode-math` packages. Note: Since the `polyglossia` package loads `fontspec` automatically, you should also take care to load `mathtools` before `polyglossia`.

For sure, if you move the instruction `\usepackage{mathtools}` to *before* both `\usepackage{polyglossia}` and `\usepackage{unicode-math}`, the `\underbrace` stuff works fine, whether or not `polyglossia` is loaded.

Comment: Nowadays there is no need to load `amsmath` before `unicode-math`; the present issue is due to `mathtools`, though. I think this has already appeared.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. I've modified my answer to incorporate your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Works after removing polyglossia--error `usexelatex`

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}    
    \[
    \underbrace{\text{A long equation}}_{\text{This is a long equation}}
    \]  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need `polyglossia` and `stix2` fonts for my project

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130304/combining-unicode-math-fonts-problems-with-underbrace

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29498/using-several-math-fonts-with-unicode-math?rq=1

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91080/197451

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290577/197451

Comment: The reason your solution "works" is *not* because you dropped loading the `polyglossia` package. Instead, it works because you (correctly!) moved the instruction `\usepackage{mathtools}` to before `\usepackage{unicode-math}`.